# Как передать параметр в callback?

Tags: javascript

Есть функция внутри метода, находящая необходимую клетку на поле:

```
    let findCell = (callback = (cell) => {}) => {
      this.field.cells.find((cell, i) => {
        if (cell.left < x && cell.right > x && cell.top < y && cell.bottom > y) {
          if (cell)
            callback.call(cell);
        }
      });
    };
```

Ну и вызов, конечно же:

```
findCell((cell) => {
   cell.open();
});
```

Проблема в том, что в коллбэке `cell` равна `undefined`, и, соответственно, метод `open()` для `undefined` не определен => я получаю ошибку. **Как добиться того, чтобы `cell` внутри коллбэка равнялась той самой клетке `cell`, которая была найдена (или не найдена, тогда коллбэк не должен выполняться) внутри самой функции `findCell()`?**

Comment: Зачем здесь `call`? `if (cell) callback(cell);`

Comment: @Igor действительно работает, спасибо. А почему `.call()` все портит?

Comment: Потому что `call` вызывает функцию в контексте своего первого параметра, с `call` `this` внутри `callback` - это `cell`.

Comment: @Igor а, ну вроде понял. Благодарю